# What happens after an openGL draw call?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to invert an image for a project, which should be as simple as scaling the projection matrix by (1, -1, 1).  However, the screen is drawn inside an API that I have no access to and no documentation on (this project is VERY old).  So performing that scaling essentially does nothing (I assume because the projection matrix is reset inside the API's call).

Do I still have access to the drawing information after a draw call, or is it cleared?  If the information still exists, how do I obtain it?

P.S. - I'm using openGL 1.1

Comment: In fixed-function pipeline, there's not much you can do after you send off the geometry with a draw call.  I think maybe you should clarify, are you trying to invert a single model, a texture or the entire scene?  The answer is different in each case.

Comment: You could try intersecting/recording the opengl commands. There should be some debugging tools available (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debugging_Tools)

Comment: racarate - My goal is to flip an entire scene, to be reflected off of a mirror.

Comment: RedAgito - Unfortunately, using any kind of 3rd party software (legit opengl debugging tools or others, such as visual leak detector) can take years to get

Comment: Are you limited to OpenGL 1.1 in the code you add? Or is it only the legacy code that is using 1.1?

Comment: Reto Koradi - Limited, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the programmer's point of view OpenGL is the worst kind of short term amnesiac imaginable. Once a drawing call returns from the programmer's perspective OpenGL already did turn everything into coloured pixels and completely forgot about what it just did.

So…

> Do I still have access to the drawing information after a draw call, or is it cleared?

No, you don't have access to it after drawing and for all practical means it is cleared.

---

However you mentioned that the legacy code is *old*. So there's a good chance that it doesn't know about shaders, i.e. will not disable or load its custom shader. So what I'd try is loading a shader with one of the older GLSL version profiles, that still have the built-in variables mapping to the old fixed function pipeline stuff and write the shader so that it does match the legacy code's needs.

Comment: datenwolf - Thanks for the response. I've been on this project for 3 months and as far as I know, there are no shaders. I'll see what I can do with this! A shader would make my life very easy.